# Reading index content, possible?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is there a way to analyze the contents of a specific index (fdb file)? I know I can see the index creation statement and try to guess from there but it would be nice if there is a way to see the contents/records inside an fdb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two tools `cbindex` and `forestdb_dump` can help. These are available in the `bin` folder along with other couchbase binaries. Note that, these tools are not supported, as documented at http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/release-notes/relnotes-40-ga.html

1. given bucket/indexname,  tool cbindex gets index level details:

   couchbases-MacBook-Pro:bin varakurprasad$ pwd
   /Users/varakurprasad/Downloads/couchbase-server-enterprise_451_GA/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin

   couchbases-MacBook-Pro:bin varakurprasad$ ./cbindex -server 127.0.0.1:8091 -type scanAll -bucket travel-sample  -limit 4 -index def_type -auth Administrator:couch1

   ScanAll index:

   [airline] ... airline_10

   [airline] ... airline_10123

   [airline] ... airline_10226

   [airline] ... airline_10642

   Total number of entries:  4
2. Given a forestdb file, the tool `forestdb_dump` gets more low level details:

   couchbases-MacBook-Pro:varakurprasad$ pwd

   /Users/varakurprasad/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data/@2i/travel-sample_def_type_1018858748122363634_0.index

   couchbases-MacBook-Pro:varakurprasad$ forestdb_dump data.fdb.53   | more

   [FDB INFO] Forestdb opened database file data.fdb.53

   DB header info:

   ```
   BID: 1568 (0x620, byte offset: 6422528)

   DB header length: 237 bytes

   DB header revision number: 3
   ```

   ...

   Doc ID: airline_10

   ```
   KV store name: back

   Sequence number: 14637

   Byte offset: 2063122

   Indexed by the main index

   Length: 10 (key), 0 (metadata), 24 (body)

   Status: normal

   Metadata: (null)

   Body:^Fairline
   ```

   ...